# Tool menu is empty on lateral bar

Tags: interface, pie-menu, empty

I'm new to Blender and my tool menu on the screen border is not visible when I click on.

I have just *Item*, *Tool*, *View* and *Create* but nothing in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are in *(Mesh) Edit Mode*, where you commonly use the editing tools in the left side bar. To gain access to the general tools in the N-Panel, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to leave or click the Dropdown Menu (labeled *Edit Mode*) in the upper left corner of the 3D View and change it to *Object Mode*.

EDIT: As John Eason stated, the N-Panel in the Edit Mode should still display *something*. If this is not the case, **you might have just collapsed the menu** (almost completely). Try dragging the separator line to the left:

[image]

Comment: He should still have the "Active Tool" entry showing in Edit mode with a mirror of the entries on the tool's toolbar.

Comment: You are totally right! I updated my answer.